# Visual Studio CMake on cloned repo with many projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I have a git repo with many many projects in it. I am trying to use MSVC with Clang-cl and CMake, Git.

I started out building a project directly in MSVC:

```
CMakePresets.json
CMakeLists.txt
asource.file.cpp
```

When I was happy with the working code, I moved these files into /repo/subfolder, and committed them.

Now I am cloning my repo as a new project: I chose to "clone repository" at MSVC project creation, and I want to avoid building the /repo root CMake project. Instead I want to build the /repo/subfolder CMake project. How can I achieve this?

Imagine I am on the Linux command line. Instead of:

```
cd myrepo
mkdir -p build && pushd build
cmake .. -G Ninja
```

I want to:

```
cd myrepo/subfolder
mkdir -p build && pushd build
cmake .. -G Ninja
```

The difference is that I want to make use of a CMake project in a subfolder instead of the root folder. I have been unable to build anything but the root project.

I've tried:

1. Right-click CMakeLists.txt and Configure CMake - it configures the top-level CMake project instead of the file I am clicking on.
2. Right-click CMakePresets.json and click all the "Add..." etc. there. It seems to edit the presets file itself.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you want to achieve and I still don't think I fully understand (and the CMake lingo makes zero sense to me). In my humble opinion, you should clarify this a little bit more and also maybe provide some more details, such as the `CMakeLists.txt` files in `repo/subfolder` and `repo/`. I will then gladly help with your issues. As a side note you are most likely only interested in `CMakeLists.txt` the `CMakePresets.json` is a pure Visual Studio thing.

Comment: @MilanŠ. [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) are not limited to Visual Studio. It is a feature built into CMake itself. Perhaps you are thinking of [CMakeSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference), which is specific to Visual Studio

Comment: I made some edits to explain what I am trying to do in terms of Linux command line

Comment: Ah you are right @starball I think I confused it with the `CMakeSettings.json`

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to have many CMake builds in one project cloned from a repo, but I figured out how to open any folder as its own CMake project:

File -> Open -> CMake...

Select the subfolder as your project. Then MSVC will trample your CMakePresets.json (truncating it to 0 bytes) which you can reset with Git -> Undo Changes. Once you have undone the changes you will want to reset the CMake cache and reconfigure in order to avoid failed CMake compilation tests.

And now it should work. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be very easy to clone a repo and then work with $project inside it.

Comment: If you want to build a number of CMakeLists.txt projects as one 'unit', then create a top-level ``CMakeLists.txt`` that uses ``add_subdirectory`` for each sub-project.

Comment: Sadly that is out of the question. This is a library, and FetchContent requires the top-level CMakeLists.txt to be the library itself. My sub-projects are demos and examples.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you want to achieve... let me clarify one thing. 
You have no problem with opening up the root level project - AS LONG AS - the subproject is it's own project (within Visual Studio) and you can "right-click -> build it" - is that correct? @gonzo

Comment: Yes, exactly! The more complete the solution is the better, I just want to be able to test and build my sub-projects independently. For example, one of my sub-projects is an example that embeds my library using FetchContent. In order for that to work it has to be fully independent.